# How can I get my column to stay inline?

Tags: html, css

2 issues here: my first column is sitting higher than the other 2, secondly, I want to be able to add 20px space to both the left and right sides of the webpage but only want to have 10px space between the middle column and the columns to the left and right sides of it. For this would I need to create 3 seperate column classes instead of the 1 I currently have?

[Website currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsNVE.png)

```
.column {
display: inline !important;
float: left;
width: 33.33%;
padding: 10px;
margin-top: 70px;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: `.column:first{}` for the first and  `.column{}` for others

Comment: Is that in terms of the first or the second issue I'm having? thank you

Comment: Can you share the full code with us in a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/pen) or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)? Thank you.

Comment: just do this `.column:first{ margin-right: 20px; margin-left: 20px; }` and this `.column{ margin-right: 10px; margin-left: 10px; }`

Comment: https://codepen.io/alex-burger/pen/bMMwdM

Comment: I am not getting `my first column is sitting higher than the other 2` issue in your codepen

Comment: It’s because `.header` navigation is floated to the right, but does not cover the full page width. This leaves space for the first content column to be displayed next to those links, but not for the following columns, so that those need to be placed further down. `clear: right;` on the first column can fix that. (Ideally though those columns would have a common wrapper element, and clear would be applied to that. Your HTML structure is generally quite _meh_ at the moment, for example for such a navigation current best practice would be an unordered list of links.)

Comment: That works perfectly :)
If you can be bothered with this, I have also been trying to indent the first lines of each column paragraph and the paragraph after the break in the first column but when I add the my indent class to them it messes everything up

Answer (score 0):

To add 20px space to both the left and right sides of the webpage wrap columns in to a wrapper div(here i added `column-container`) and give it `padding: 0 10px;` and your columns already has 10px padding so now your webpage has total 20px padding on both side. 
**Edit**: 
add `<div class="clear"></div>` after `header` and apply css `.clear { clear: both; }`

```css
a, abbr, acronym, address, applet, article, aside, audio, b, big, blockquote,
body, canvas, caption, center, cite, code, dd, del, details, dfn, dialog,
div, dl, dt, em, embed, fieldset, figcaption, figure, font, footer, form,
header, hgroup, hr, html, i, iframe, img, ins, kbd, label, legend, li, mark,
menu, meter, nav, object, ol, output, p, pre, progress, q, rp, rt, ruby, s,
samp, section, small, span, strike, strong, sub, summary, sup, table, tbody,
td, tfoot, th, thead, time, tr, tt, u, ul, var, video {
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
}

body, html {
    background-color: white

}

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, section {
    display: block
}

body {
      max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
}

.header2 {
    display: inline;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: left !important;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    float: left;

}

.header {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: right !important;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: right;
    float: right;

}



p {
  font-family: Helvetica, serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 100;
    display: inline;
    margin-top: 40px;



-webkit-hyphens: auto;
   -moz-hyphens: auto;
    -ms-hyphens: auto;
        hyphens: auto;

    word-wrap: break-word;
}



.column {
  display: inline !important;
    float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 70px;
  box-sizing: border-box;

}

h1 {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 48px;
    font-weight: 100;
    display: inline;
       padding: 15px;
    margin-top: 10px ;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    word-break: break-word;
}

h2 {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 48px;
    font-weight: 100;
    display: inline;
       padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
    word-break: break-word;
    
}

h3 {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 100;
        padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline;
}

h4 {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 100;
        padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline;
}

h5 {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 100;
        padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline;
}

a { color:black} /* Globally */

/* Each state */

a:visited { text-decoration: none !important; color:black; }
a:hover { text-decoration: none !important; color:black; }
a:hover, a:active { text-decoration: none  !important; color:black }
}

div {
    text-decoration: none  !important;
}

.footer{
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin-top:10px;
    bottom: 0px;
    position: relative;
}

.footer1 a{
    border: 2px solid #000;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 0 0 0px;
}

.footer2 {
    bottom: 0px !important;
    right: 0px;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
        display: inline !important;
}

.contentwrapper{
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
margin:0 auto;
width:98vw;

}

.main-carousel{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 70px;
}

.carousel-cell{
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.carousel-cell img{
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
}


.main-carousel img {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}


html, body{
    height: 100%
}

/* Barber CSS */

.link{
transition:.2s all;
cursor: pointer;
}

.link:hover{
text-decoration:underline;
    
}

a{
text-decoration: none;
}

.flickity-prev-next-button.previous {
    left: 10px;
    display: block;
    opacity: 1!important;
  }

.flickity-prev-next-button.next{
  right: 10px;
  display: block;
  opacity: 1!important;
  }

.flickity-button{
  background:none!important;
}
.flickity-prev-next-button .arrow {
    fill: white!important;
}

.indent{
  text-indent: 70px;
  word-break: break-word;
}

.header-item{
padding:px;
}

@media(max-width:700px){

  .column {
    display: inline !important;
      float: left;
    width: 90%;
      padding: 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
  }

  .header div h1{

    font-size:16px;
    max-width:100%;
  }

}

li {
 font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 100;
    display: inline;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-top: 70px
}

img {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    display: block;
    padding-right: 20px !important;
}

.column-container {
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="flickity.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.min.css">


<!-- You were just missing JQuery. This is a very important javascript library you will need for most projects. If you have JS problems in future
start by including the link below -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <title>ALEX BURGER</title>
</head>


    <body>

            <!-- JS -->
     <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="flickity.pkgd.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>

     <div class="header2">
         <div class ="header-item">
              <a href="index.html"><h1 class ="link">ALEX BURGER</h1></a>
         
             <div class ="header-item">      
             <a href=""><h2>HELLO@ALEX.BURGER.DE</h2></a>
        
        
    <div class="header">
      <div class ="header-item">
       
      </div>
      <div class ="header-item">
       <a href="Grafik%20Design.html"><h3 class ="link">GRAFIK DESIGN</h3></a>
          </div>
       <div class ="header-item">
      <a href="Photography.html"><h4 class ="link">PHOTOGRAPHY</h4></a>
           </div>
       <div class ="header-item">
       <a href="fonts.html"><h5 class ="link">FONTS (1)</h5></a>
           </div>
       </div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="column-container">
<div class="column"><p>ALEX BURGER<br>
    I am a Graphic Designer/ Photographer with a strong focus on typography and editorial design.<br> I am interested in how design and photography can be combined to communicate ideas around social sciences; especially gender and masculinity. As well as creating a space that aims to be all inclusive.
        </p>
    </div>

<div class="column"><p>EDUCATION<br>
    2014-18 Massey University
          Wellington, New Zealand.
          Bachelor of Design, Honours
          First Class. Visual Communication Design.<br></p>
       <div class ="indent">
        <p>WORK EXPERIENCE<br>
            </div>

            <p>GS1 New Zealand: Geromino Team<br>
                Positions: Photographer<br></p>
            <div class ="indent"><p>Photo Editor<br></p></div>

        </div>

<div class="column"><p>CONTACT<br>
    Location: Currently based in Berlin.
           Available for freelance work.<br>

         <div class ="indent">
        <p>hello@alex.burger.de<br></p>

            </div>

        <p>(+49) 0152 28165191<br></p>


        <div class ="indent">
            <p>TECHNICAL<br>
                </div>
            <p>Photoshop. Indesign. Illustrator.
                Editorial &amp; Book Design.
                Studio &amp; Product Photography. Exhibition Design</p>

            <div class ="indent">
            <p>
                HTML &amp; CSS.
                </p></div>

</div>
               </div>


        <div class="contentwrapper">


         <div class="main-carousel" data-flickity='{ "cellAlign": "left", "contain": true, "wrapAround": true, "autoPlay": true}'>

            <div class="carousel-cell">
                <img src ="GenerationAnxiety.01.jpg"></div>

             <div class="carousel-cell">
                <img src ="GenerationAnxiety.02.jpg"></div>

            <div class="carousel-cell">
                <img src ="GenerationAnxiety.03.jpg"></div>

            <div class="carousel-cell">
                <img src ="GenerationAnxiety.04.jpg"></div>

            <div class="carousel-cell">
                <img src ="GenerationAnxiety.05.jpg"></div>





        </div>




        <div class="footer">
            <div class="footer1">

        <p>&copy; Alex Burger. All rights reserved<br>Further information can be requested through email.</p>

                <div class="footer2">
                   
                <a href="Grafik%20Design.html"> <p>hello@alex.burger.de</p></a>
            </div>
           
            
            
           
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: any idea why the first column is sitting higher up than the other 2?

Comment: I have no idea try to give `vertical-align: top;` to column

Comment: which browser you are using?

Comment: Wait i got the issue this is due to float

Comment: If you can be bothered with this, I have also been trying to indent the first lines of each column paragraph and the paragraph after the break in the first column but when I add the my indent class to them it messes everything up